# Manage Facebook Page - Add sections Tabs

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, tabs, facebook-page

We want to manage a facebook page using php/mysql and php-facebook-sdk, we have a site with the sections below: About Us , Services, Projects, Contact Us.Each section contains data. We want to add programmatically a tabs sections called About Us , Services, Projects, Contact Us in the Facebook page related included a links to the site. We understand the creation of application on Facebook first, but the question is how proceed to use the facebook php-sdk or api's(graph api) related to do that? or any tutorials exist for this reason?how proceed to add new tabs with titles, and add data using php/mysql with this data?
We want to do exactly like the tabs in the page below:
https://www.facebook.com/doreuk
(About Dore, Contact us,....)

Thank you for your suggestions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A facebook tab is a page on your (own) server framed in by facebook. So create a html page, make it available under http and https.  Next follow the instruction in this tutorial:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

1. create your page
2. create a new app developers.facebook.com
3. choose page tab
4. install your app by visting: `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL`

You don't need to use the facebook php-sdk or api's(graph api) to do this!

Comment: or wen can display an php page when we click on some tab?

Comment: What's can be the next url param (next=YOUR_URL)?